# Ubuntu. Sending emails with embedded images

Tags: email, ubuntu, sendmail

I have Ubuntu server(16.04) + Nagios, also I have created a script that makes a screenshot(Nagios status) every night and sends this screenshot to two recipients. But occurs problem, I receive mail with images(embed in a body, not attachment) - is OK, but my friend receives the same mail with broken images(blank files in attachment). 
Any suggestion, how to solve this problem?
Script code:

```
    #!/bin/bash

cat <<EOT | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
TO: @email1, @email2
SUBJECT: Report: Nagios Event Log  $(date +%F --date=yesterday)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/related;boundary="XYZ"

--XYZ
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff" text="#000000">
Hello Team,<br>Daily Nagios report of $(date +%F --date=yesterday) is generated.
<img src="cid:part1.06090408.01060107" alt="">
<br>Best Regards, Nagios Admin
</body>
</html>

--XYZ
Content-Type: image/png;name="Nagios-EventLog-`date +%F --date="yesterday"`.png"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part1.06090408.01060107>
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="Nagios-EventLog-`date +%F --date="yesterday"`.png"
$(base64 /some_path/NagiosReport/Nagios-EventLog-`date +%F --date="yesterday"`.png)
--XYZ--
EOT
```

Comment: if it works for you but not your friend, maybe your friends email client does not correctly support inline embedded images

Comment: @chiliNUT, It can be a reason, we didn't think about that. Need to check it. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lack a newline between the MIME headers and the base64 image data.

Running `base64` in a command substitution inside a here document will probably produce overlong lines in the output. Try (rough pseudocode)

```
( cat <<EOF
  From: blah blah ...
  Subject: blah blah ...
  :
  --XYZ
  Content-description: image/png; name=etc etc

  EOF

  base64 file

  printf "\n--XYZ--\n" ) | sendmail -oi -t
```

(I'm assuming you did `PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH` near the top of the script so you don't have to hard-code the path to `sendmail`.)

If improved knowledge of MIME isn't a personal development goal, probably use a program which knows how to do this properly.  Many people use `mutt` to send mail on their behalf without having to worry about how exactly to do it right.

As a stylistic aside, running `$(date +%F)` multiple times seems clunky. Just run it once and capture the output in a variable. (In the pathological case, the script runs around midnight, and you get different dates in different parts of the message!)

Comment: If your message doesn't actually contain any Latin-9 (iso-8859-15) data, why bother specifying a character set, and in particular a legacy 8-bit character set? You should probably standardize on UTF-8 if you are not happy with just good old US-ASCII from the friendly, friendly US Department of Defence.

Comment: Hi, @tripleee. Thanks you for suggestion, but I think, this script works OK and my friend had some problems with accepting images in message body. But I investigate your proposal and will try to modify my script with your recomendation. Thanks

Comment: The overlong lines might make it inside your local network but get chopped up when you send to a mail server outside of your organization. Both of these issues (the long lines, and the missing neck between the MIME headers and the image body data) are violations of the MIME format so you want to try fixing these for a start in any event.